# python: read a file and interpret contents

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with airlines, airports, and passenger counts, and I want to find the first flight with less than 100 passengers. Here is my file:

```
Alitalia  Rome  180
Alitalia  Pisa 82
Germanwings Munich 96
Wizzair Frankfurt 83
Wizzair Lisbon 198
```

I tried to use this code :

```
with open('airlines.txt','r') as f:
document_text = f.readlines()
document_text= [line.split() for line in content]
text_string = document_text.lower()

passenger = 100
for n in text_string:
     if n < passenger:
         print(n)
    else:
         print('there is no flight with passengers less than 100')
```

and I got this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Split the string and convert last item to int: `if int(n.split(' ')[-1]) < passenger:`

Comment: i tried this it doesn't work dude

Comment: Can you be more specific about why it doesn't work?

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp  I wanna print the WHOLE LINEe that contains the first flight less than 100 passenger.  like " Alitalia  Pisa 82 "

Comment: There are other issues. What is `content`? You can't call `lower` on a list.

Comment: here is the error when i converted to int :                                                                                          if int(n.split(' ')[-1]) < passenger:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'

Comment: @ Johnny Mopp lower is already worked fine in the same code , I made it just to convert all capitalize letters.

Comment: Just use a pandas.DataFrame.  Read the docs, very powerful data structure and perfect for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. You were comparing the wrong data type.
This works if you have the following format: `string string string/int` with space in between.

```
with open('sample.txt','r') as f:
    document_text = f.read()

text_string = document_text.lower() # not necesary in this context
passenger = 100


for iter, n in enumerate(text_string.split('\n')):
    if int(n.split()[2]) < passenger:
         print(n)
         break
    elif iter == len(text_string.split('.n')) :
        print('there is no flight with passengers less than 100')
```

Comment: that worked fine man , but it prints all the flight with passengers less than 100 ,  I want Just THE FIRST ONE  " by respecting the order in the file "

Comment: thanks dude it worked good , but it print this : germanwings munich 96

Comment: the right answer should be this :  Alitalia  Pisa 82,     I'm trying to modify it

Comment: That's strange, check it here [online compiler](https://repl.it/repls/ElderlyForkedCommas)

Comment: really strange , it wroks fine , I don't know why it return me :  Germanwings Munich 96.

Comment: have you replaced the name of the file from my code? (`airlines.txt` instead of `sample.txt` There in the online compiler you could see/edit the source `txt` file as you want and still see that the code is working.

Comment: You're welcome! Did you did some modification to it? You got me curious :)

Comment: @ andreis11 nope i don't need to modify now its perfect dude thanks. i wanna just ask u something about the same code if u have some minutes there is a chat section here to chat with u???

Comment: I guess that might be possible through a chatroom, but I don't enter them too often.